why joblib.parallel may not work when using the function with xml.etree.ElementTree
I use the function to parse XML and write information to a table. For a large amount of XML, I want to use Joblib.Parallel, but when specifying n_jobs=-1, the processor is not even loaded by 30%. What could be wrong?
def parsing_contract(xml_data, ucdb_id):
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data[xml_data.id == str(ucdb_id)].xml_new.values[0])
contract = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0, len(root.findall(".//preply/report/Account"))))

contract['ucdb_id']  = ucdb_id
contract['cred_update'] = [i.text for i in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account/lastUpdatedDt")]
contract['cred_update'] = [i.text for i in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account/lastUpdatedDt")]
contract['cred_update'] = contract['cred_update'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))
contract['cred_date'] = [x.findall('tr')[-1].findall('openedDt')[-1].text for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
contract['cred_enddate'] = [x.findall('tr')[-1].findall('closeDt')[-1].text if x.findall('trade')[-1].findall('closeDt') else '9999-12-31' for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
tradeTypeCode = [x.findall('trade')[-1].findall('Type')[-1].text if x.findall('trade')[-1].findall('Type') else None for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
acctType = [x.findall('trade')[-1].findall('acctType')[-1].text if x.findall('tr')[-1].findall('acctType') else None for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
loanKindCode = [x.findall('tr')[-1].findall('Code)[-1].text if x.findall('tr')[-1].findall('Code') else None for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
contract['cred_type'] = [cred_type(i,k,j) for i,k,j in zip(tradeTypeCode, acctType, loanKindCode)]

contract['principal'] = [float(x.findall('due')[-1].findall('principal')[-1].text) if x.findall('due') and x.findall('due')[-1].findall('principal') else np.nan for x in root.findall(".//preply/report/Account")]
return contract

with parallel_config('multiprocessing', prefer="threads"):
results = Parallel(backend="multiprocessing", n_jobs=-1, verbose = 10, batch_size=4048)(delayed(parsing_contract)(xml_data, ucdb_id) for ucdb_id in xml_data.id.values)

here was also an option to use the function below, but it also gives a load of only 50%:
def parsing_contract(xml_data, ucdb_id):
xmltodict_new = xmltodict.parse(xml_data[xml_data.id == str(ucdb_id)].xml_new.values[0])
xml_contract = xmltodict_new['product']['preply']['report']['Account'] if 'uuid' not in xmltodict_new['product']['preply']['report']['Account'] else pd.DataFrame({key: [values] for key, values in xmltodict_new['product']['preply']['report']['Account'].items()})
contract = pd.DataFrame(xml_contract)
contract = contract.dropna(subset = ['tr', 'serialNum'])
contract['ucdb_id']  = ucdb_id
contract['cred_update'] = contract['lastUpdatedDt'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))

contract[['cred_date','cred_enddate', 'cred_type']] = np.array(list(contract.tr.apply(lambda x: trade(x)).values))
contract['sort_date'] = pd.to_datetime(contract['cred_date'])
contract = contract.sort_values('sort_date').iloc[-m:]
if 'due' in contract.columns:
    contract['principal'] = contract.due.apply(lambda x: dueArrear(x)).values
else:
    contract['principal'] = np.nan
contract['type_new'] = contract.T.apply(lambda x: active_new(x)).values
contract['enddate'] = contract.T.apply(lambda x: enddate_new(x)).values
return contract

